# Using a while loop to go back to start

Tags: java

/*---------------------------------------
-----------------Quizzes.java------------
----------------------------------------*/
   import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Quizzes
   {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {

```
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        NumberFormat per = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();     


  //User to input keys for quiz
     System.out.println("How many questions are in the quiz?");
     int numques = scan.nextInt();
     int[] keys = new int[numques];

     for (int i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
     {
        System.out.print("Please enter the key for # " + (i+1)+ ": " );
        keys[i] = scan.nextInt();         
     }

  //User to input answer
     System.out.println("\nGrading Quizzes");
     System.out.println("--------------------");

        int correct=0;

     for (int i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
     {
        System.out.println("Please enter the answer for # " + (i+1)+ ":  ");
        int answer= scan.nextInt();
            if (answer== keys [i])
            {
                System.out.print("Number "+(i+1)+" is correct.\n");
                correct++;
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.print("Number "+(i+1)+" is incorrect.\n");

            }
     }
    double cal=(double) correct/numques;
        System.out.println("Total number of correct is "+correct);
     System.out.println("The percent correct is " +per.format(cal));

        System.out.println("Would you like to grade another quiz? (y/n)");
        String user_input=scan.next();

        while(user_input.equals("y"))
        {   correct=0;
     for (int i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
     {
        System.out.println("Please enter the answer for # " + (i+1)+ ":  ");
        int answer= scan.nextInt();
            if (answer== keys [i])
            {
                System.out.print("Number "+(i+1)+" is correct.\n");
                correct++;
            }
            else {
            System.out.print("Number "+(i+1)+" is incorrect.\n");   }

            } 
           cal=(double) correct/numques;
           System.out.println("Total number of correct is "+correct);
        System.out.println("The percent correct is " +per.format(cal));
      }
           System.out.println("Goodbye!");

 }
```

}

How would I make the program go back to where the user would have to enter the answer using the while loop? No matter what I tried, right when it prints out, "Would you like to grade another quiz, and if the user type y, it would just end. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong

Edit 1: Well I got it to re-run again after the while loop but it keep asking me to input the answer for the question over and over and over again, it doesn't break out of the loop,it doesn't go back to the part where it asked if I wanted to grade another. This is the output

How many questions are in the quiz?
2
Please enter the key for # 1: 1
Please enter the key for # 2: 2

### Grading Quizzes

Please enter the answer for # 1:
1
Number 1 is correct.
Please enter the answer for # 2:
3
Number 2 is incorrect.
Total number of correct is 1
The percent correct is 50%
Would you like to grade another quiz? (y/n)
y
Please enter the answer for # 1:
1
Number 1 is correct.
Please enter the answer for # 2:
2
Number 2 is correct.
Total number of correct is 2
The percent correct is 100%
Please enter the answer for # 1:
1
Number 1 is correct.
Please enter the answer for # 2:
2
Number 2 is correct.
Total number of correct is 2
The percent correct is 100%
Please enter the answer for # 1:

Comment: Shouldn't the user_input be within the while loop? The program is badly formatted and difficult to understand.

Comment: Your method (`main`) is too long for humans to reason about.  Suggest you pull out a couple of inner methods, which will make it easier to reason about the control flow you're looking at.  @allthenutsandbolts provides a decent outline to get started...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(user_input.equals('y'))
```

should be

```
while(user_input.equals("y")) // see the double quotes here
```

Problem with your code is that character 'y' is autoboxed to instance of `Character` class which is the subclass of [Object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

> Class Object is the root of the class
>   hierarchy. Every class has Object as a
>   superclass. All objects, including
>   arrays, implement the methods of this
>   class

So is the candidate for `public boolean equals(Object)`.

`String` implementation of `boolean equals(Object)` checks whether the instance is of type `String`. if it fails, it will simply return `false`.
If you want to compare with `'y'`, then try this.

```
while(user_input.equals(((Character)'y').toString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I will put the question a while loop and it will be something like

```
while (true) {

 // ask the users the questions 

 // ask if he wants to continue... if no then break; else continue
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ok add a `while(true)` at the beginning of your program and add the appropriate brackets to encompass the whole method's contents. Then, delete the current while loop you have. Say after you get your input for user_input:

```
if (user_input.equals("y")) {
}
else {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will replace this while with your `while(user_input.equals("y"))` loop and the problem you pointed will go away but i think still your code will not work as you expected. I think your will need these more correction on your code

1. while loop should be this one `while(user_input.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))`
2. Put the opening and closing braces for while loop and in end while after finishing your for loop put these two statement to check again and again.
3. follow the following snap of code

   while(user_input.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
       {

   ```
       for (int i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
       {
           ....               
       }

       System.out.println("Would you like to grade another quiz? (y/n)");
       user_input=scan.next();
   }
   ```